# If/else statement Lua

Tags: if-statement, lua, coronasdk

Each time the arithmetic question is generated and whenever i pick the right or wrong answer the statement of function checkanswer() always goes on if-statement "Correct". How am i able to create if/else statement correctly base on an arithmetic question varanswer = var1 + var2

```
 function checkAnswer(event)

if(#theAnswer == questionGen()) then
        instructionsText.text = "Correct!";
        instructionsText:toFront()
        generateBalls()
        for i=1, allBallsGroup.numChildren do
            display.remove(allBallsGroup[1])
        end
    else
        instructionsText.text = "Incorrect!";
        instructionsText:toFront()
        generateBalls()
        for i=1, allBallsGroup.numChildren do
            display.remove(allBallsGroup[1])
        end
    end
end


function questionGen()

 local questionVar1 = display.newImage("ygSquare.png", 150, 500); 
 local var1 = math.random(1,9)
 local var1Display =display.newText(var1, 200, 500, native.systemFont, 200)
 questionVar1.width = 200
 questionVar1.height = 200
 questionVar1.x = 350
 questionVar1.y = 500
 var1Display.x = 350
 var1Display.y = 500
 var1Display:setTextColor("#000000")
 local questionVar2 = display.newImage("blueSquare.png", 150, 500);
 local var2 = math.random(1,9)
 local var2Display = display.newText(var2, 200, 500, native.systemFont, 200)
 questionVar2.width = 200
 questionVar2.height = 200
 questionVar2.x = 700
 questionVar2.y = 500
 var2Display.x = 700
 var2Display.y = 500
 var2Display:setTextColor("#000000")
 local operator = "         +     " 
 local operatorDisplay = display.newText(operator, 400, 500, native.systemFont, 200)
 operatorDisplay:setTextColor("#000000")
 local varAnswer = var1 + var2
 return varAnswer

end
```

Comment: Where's `theAnswer` variable is set in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Your random values are greater than 1 and adding two numbers greater than 1, will be greater than 1. This means that `questionGen()` is always returning true. I would divide `var1` and `var2` by 9 so that it is normalized. Also you will need to add a line to check if `varAnswer` say greater than 1 (0.5+05) return true else return false.

```
function questionGen()

 local varAnswer = var1/9 + var2/9
 if(varAnswer>=1) then return true end
 return false
end
```

Now in your other function you can check `if(questionGen()) then`

Comment: Macroland i did what you said about the varAnswer if it is > 1 and yes you have given me an idea how would i work this code but still always returning true.. i modified "if(#theAnswer == questionGen()) then" into "if(questionGen(varAnswer) > 1 ) then"..

Comment: `if(questionGen(varAnswer)>1)` statement will not work as your `varAnswer` in `questionGen()` is sum of two random outcomes. Btw, in your post I am still not sure where `theAnswer` comes from.

Comment: Macro the checkAnswer() and local varAnswer = var1/9 + var2/9 is now working but it has logical error which the inputs became decimal, My game is usually generates arithmetic question addition and its a multiple choice and the input are whole numbers. I feel dumb right now cause i can't do the math well :(

Comment: If you can show in the statement `if(#theAnswer == questionGen())` where `thenAnswer` variable comes from, maybe it will be easier to take this further.

Comment: Check my Answer Macro i can't put the code statement

Answer (score 0):

This is use to create inputs or choices in my game macro

```
local theAnswer= ""; 
local theAnswerText;

function createBall()

local var numberArray = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"};
local tens = {questionGen(#theAnswer)}
local ballType = math.random(8);
local ballSize = math.random(2)
local letterIndex
local letter
if(createTens == true) then

   letterIndex = math.random(#tens)
   letter = tens[letterIndex];
else
 letterIndex = math.random(#numberArray);
 letter = numberArray[letterIndex];
  letterIndex = math.random(#tens)
   letter = tens[letterIndex];
end

local ballGroup = display.newGroup();
local ball
local ballRadius
if(ballType == 1) then
     ball = display.newImage("whiteBall.png"); 
elseif(ballType == 2) then
     ball = display.newImage("brownBall.png");
elseif(ballType == 3) then
     ball = display.newImage("pinkBall.png");
elseif(ballType == 4) then
     ball = display.newImage("whiteBall.png");
elseif(ballType == 5) then
     ball = display.newImage("yellowBall.png");
elseif(ballType == 6) then
     ball = display.newImage("whiteBall.png");
elseif(ballType == 7) then
     ball = display.newImage("greenBall.png");
else
     ball = display.newImage("redBall.png");
end
if(ballSize == 1)then
    ball.width  = 200;
    ball.height = 200;
    ballRadius = 30;
else
    ball.width = 200;
    ball.height = 200;
    ballRadius = 30;    
end

local letterText = display.newText( letter, 0,0, native.systemFontBold, 100 );
letterText:setTextColor(0,0, 0);
letterText.x = ball.x;
letterText.y = ball.y;
ballGroup:insert(ball);
ballGroup:insert(letterText);
ballGroup.x = math.random(ballRadius,display.contentWidth-ballRadius*3);
ballGroup.y= 40;
physics.addBody(ballGroup, 'dynamic',{friction = 0,bounce = 0,radius = ballRadius*3});
ballGroup.name = "ball";
ballGroup.letter = letter;

ballGroup:addEventListener('tap',checkAnswer);
table.insert(allBalls,ballGroup)
allBallsGroup:insert(ballGroup)
```

end

Comment: Since your code is not very clear, at least to me, so to be on the same page: Are you trying to get a random number between 1-18 and depending on the number, you are selecting a ball of a color and showing that ball on the screen? OR Are you trying to show randomly 9 balls on the screen and testing based on a criteria whether the user has selected the right ball. Sorry without clearly understanding what you are doing it is hard to take it further.

Comment: To make it clear i change local "tens = {questionGen(#theAnswer)}" to local "tens = {questionGen(varAnswer)}" . 1-18 array are the varAnswer ill show you the video capture of my game heres the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvF3-Po-wHI&feature=youtu.be

Comment: `ballGroup:addEventListener('tap',checkAnswer);` are you sure you are reading the right number on the ball on which the user clicks as answer.

Comment: yes macro im really sure about it, im just having a problem with checkAnswer function.. all of the ballgroup are whole numbers,,

Comment: If that's the case your function looks correct to me, except I realized that you have `theAnswer` variable as string and you are comparing the length of the string with the sum of the random numbers generated, which doesnt make sense to me.